# Code formatting, global settings in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Can I switch on word wrap in IntelliJ IDEA globally, not for the current project only? Besides, can I get rid of rewriting long lines of text in the form of concatenation? I turned wrap in File -> Settings -> Code Style (Right margin (columns) ... wrap on typing, but still when I use System.out.println("Some long-long line") it appears to be concatenated at first, and I have to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the code formatting settings are organized in schemes, not for the current project.

Open the "Settings"-Dialog, go to "Editor" --> "Code Style" and activate "Wrap on typing". Long lines will be wrapped while you're typing. If you insert a long line from the clipboard, the wrapping is done after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (Windows).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did'n know about Ctrl+Alt+L, useful info.

Comment: if it's useful, please accept the answer. That's common use on stack overflow